# How to dynamically create a union instance in c++?

Tags: c++, instance, unions

I need to have several instances of a union as class variables, so how can I create a union instance in the heap? thank you

Comment: Instance variables or class variables? Unions or pointers-to-union?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same as creating any other object:

```
union MyUnion
{
   unsigned char charValue[5];
   unsigned int  intValue;
};


MyUnion *myUnion = new MyUnion;
```

Your union is now on the heap. Note that a union is the size of it's largest data member.

Answer (score 2):

My C++ is a bit rusty, but:

```
   my_union_type *my_union = new my_union_type;
   ...
   delete my_union;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as a struct :) You can use `malloc()` and do it the C way, or `new` for the C++ way. The secret is that structs, unions and classes are related; a struct is just a class (usually) without methods. There's more clarification in the following comments, should you care.

Comment: A struct in C++ may have methods.  A struct and class are very similar except that a struct has public members/functions by default while a class has private members by default.

Comment: No, you can have methods in structs.  You can even derive structs from classes and vice-versa.  About the only difference between struct and class is that the default access for a struct is public, while it's private for a class.

Comment: In C++, a struct can have methods.  The main difference between a struct and a class is that the default access for a class is private while the default access for a struct is public.

Comment: Struct can have methods in C++, the main difference between class and struct is that the default scope for struct is public while its private for class.

Comment: OK OK, you can stop bashing me now.

Comment: Yeah, that was quite a dog pile.  8v)

Comment: You might find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654609/how-much-functionality-is-acceptable-for-a-c-struct

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'd consider it in rather poor taste to cross-purpose the two so I'd forgotten C++ lets you do it anyway. "C++: The fully automatic foot-targeting bazooka!" :)

Comment: Methods in structs? Heck, with C++ you can even have methods in _unions_ !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you want to head with this. A union is a user-defined data or class type that, at any given time, contains only one object from its list of members. So starting from this, if you have a union defined like this:

```
union DataType
{
    char ch;
    integer i;
    float f;
    double d;
};
```

You can then use `DataType` as a type to define members in a class or as a type to define variables on the stack, just like regular types, struct or classes you define.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` operator:

```
#include <iostream>

union u {
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
};

class c {
public:
  c() { u1 = new u; u2 = new u; u3 = new u; }
  ~c() { delete u1; delete u2; delete u3; }
  u *u1;
  u *u2;
  u *u3;
};

int main()
{
  c *p = new c;

  p->u1->a = 1;
  p->u2->b = '0' + 2;
  p->u3->c = 3.3;

  std::cout << p->u1->a << '\n'
            << p->u2->b << '\n'
            << p->u3->c << std::endl;

  delete c;

  return 0;
}
```